# How to refresh the Iframe url with Loading Image display

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I want animate the I-Frame Loading its Source Page.  I partially achieved my goal by using    JavaScript   code goes like this

```
function reloadIt()
{
    frm=document.getElementsByName("pagers")[0];      //we get the iframe object
    frm.src=frm.src;        //or you can set the src to a new src
    setTimeout("reloadIt()",100000);         //the function will run every 60000 miliseconds, or 60 seconds
}
```

and my  HTMl Body code goes here

```
<body onload="reloadIt()">
```

and my IFRAME  Code Goes like this

```
<div id="divLoading">
    <div style="width:100%; height:200px; align="center"> 
        <img src="loader.gif" alt="" align="absmiddle"/> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divFrameHolder" style="display:none">
    <iframe  src="lead.php" height="450px;" width="100%"  name="pagers"  onload="hideLoading()" > </iframe>`
</div>
```

and this works fine when this html page loads at first Time ,we can see loading Image in Iframe till Its source page loads. but after time interval when IFrame refreshes  there is no loading image and its simply reloads its source page   ...  Can any body help me?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at BlockUi, a jquery plugin. (http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#element). Try something like this:

```
function reloadIt() {
       $("#iframeholder").block({
            message: '<img src="css/ajax-loader.gif"/>',
            css: { width: "600px;", height: "400px;" }
        });
        $('#pagers').attr('src', $('#pagers').attr("src"));
        $('#iframeholder').unblock()
        setTimeout("reloadIt()", 5000);
}
```